# jwplayer xml playlist custom tags

Tags: xml, jwplayer, playlist, custom-tags

i'm using jwplayer 5.7 in my application to run videos. I'm trying to create a playlist in which im using custom tags that i need for my own custom js. Following is an excerpt of my xml playlist.

```
<title>Webisode 200 Playlist</title>

<item>

  <title>My first video</title>

  <media:credit role="author">Adam Houston</media:credit>

  <media:content url="rackspace_url" type="video/x-flv" />

  <jwplayer:deanlongdescription>Very long description goes here.</jwplayer:deanlongdescription>

</item> 

<item>

  <title>Other Video 202</title>

  <media:credit role="author">Brent Purcell</media:credit>

  <media:content url="rackspace_url" type="video/x-flv" />

  <jwplayer:deanlongdescription>Very long description goes here.</jwplayer:deanlongdescription>

</item>
```

according to the jwplayer forums/doc i need to include jwplayer namespace to include the tag but when i do jwplayer.getPlayers()[0].getPlaylistItem().deanlongdescription in firebug i get undefined, whereas i can access other properties. Any suggestions??

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution,

all i have to do is to include the namespace in the rss tag as follows:

<\rss version='2.0' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:jwplayer='http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/FlashFormats\>

and then inside each  i could do <\jwplayer:custom_tag>custom_value</jwplayer:custom_tag>

and that's it, simple!